# Глагол совершенного вида и "второй день подряд"

Tags: глаголы, аспектология

Скажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли употреблять выражение "второй день подряд" с глаголом совершенного времени прошедшего времени? Например: *Второй день подряд выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса.* Меня смущает, что, по моему ощущению, слово "подряд" подразумевает какое-то длительное действие, которое, возможно, не закончено, а глагол совершенного вида — законченное действие.

Comment: Убрал лишнее "то".

Answer (score 1):

> Второй день подряд выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса.

Да, в предложении нарушена классическая грамматика.
Нельзя что-то "сделать два дня (подряд)". Можно только "делать". Два раза можно. А два дня - это уже какая-то продолженность действия, она требует глагола несовершенного вида. И то, что у вас не два дня, а "второй день" по большому счету не спасает, хотя результат и выглядит не так страшно.

Проблема в том, что исправить вот так просто не удается. Нет в русском языке подходящей видо-временной формы, чтобы и многократно, и продолженно. И вот эта грамматическая недостаточность приводит к появлению фраз подобных вашему примеру.

Я уже сталкивался с подобным.
Типа "два дня подряд пришел на работу с опозданием". Естественно, что в данном случае можно пожертвовать законченностью действия и написать "приходил" - строго по грамматике. Или вот, из уже из СМИ: "На турнире в Нью-Йорке второй день подряд на трибуны пришел енот", "В Тегеране протестующие второй день подряд вышли на антиправительственные митинги" - ну вот как такое править?

И как быть с этим самым коронавирусом - не знаю. Конечно, любой мало-мальски годный редактор исправит на ***"два дня подряд выявляли"***, но семантика  не просто законченности, но и результативности теста уйдет... И вот это проблема останется, как бы мы не перестраивали фразу. Ну разве уж что-то очень длинное и/или далекое от исходного. ***"Ежедневные тесты два раза подряд выявили"*** - надо оно вам такое?

Иногда подобная грамматическая недостаточность (нельзя, но очень надо) приводит к возникновению новой нормы. Но сомневаюсь, что с данным примером что-то подобное произойдет. Очень уж против шерсти придется грамматику приглаживать...

Comment: Нельзя что-то "сделать два дня (подряд)". Можно только "делать" - Согласна. Подскажите, а есть ли конкретное правило по этому поводу? Почему в данном случае нужен глагол несовершенного вида? А то пытаюсь доказать коллегам, что это коряво звучит, но аргументировать чем-то, кроме как "я так чувствую", не могу) Не нахожу такого правила.

Comment: @Анастасия  Да было бы правило под рукой - я бы вам его сразу и сказал. А так... надо просто перечитать грамматику всего русского глагола, или хотя бы категории вида... Хотя знаете, где может быть? В учебниках РКИ (русский как иностранный). Там такие вещи разжевывают. Но у меня этих учебников нет - и никогда не было.

Comment: Хотя... посмотрите http://www.fio.ru/pravila/grammatika/kategoriya-vida-glagola/ - здесь сказано про употребление глаголов совершенного вида. Многократность там не упоминается вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Поищу. Но в приведенной вами ссылке, кажется, есть что-то похожее (Глаголы совершенного вида не могут сочетаться с наречиями и словосочетаниями, выражающими значение неограниченной длительности или повторяемости).

Comment: Ну да, что-то там есть, конечно. Я ж не зря вам эту ссылку дал. ))) Если подойдет для дискуссии, буду рад.

Answer (score 0):

Замечательное предложение, иллюстрирующее "второй тип" обстоятельств.

Обстоятельства в 99.99% случаев можно логически (вопросом) отнести не к основе предложения, а непосредственно к глаголу (отглагольный вопрос):

"В санатории все было приготовлено для лечения отдыхающих;"
Было (для чего?) для лечения. Было (где?) В санатории.

Надо очень постараться, чтобы найти обстоятельство, несоотносимое с глаголом путём логического вопроса, а соотносимое лишь с основой целиком. И, кажется, вам это удалось.

"Второй день подряд выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса."

логически эквивалентно:

"Второй день подряд оказывается, что выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса."

ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ:

Но последнее предложение в форме:
"Уже месяц верно, что выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса в день."
не имеет особого смысла. А значит, исходное выражение также некорректно.

Как обычно, заменой перфект времени может послужить пассивный залог:

> Второй день подряд выявлено менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса.

> Два дня подряд у тебя опоздания на работу

Comment: Хотите сказать, что в предложении "Второй день подряд выявили менее 16 тысяч случаев коронавируса" все верно, нет ошибки?

Comment: Думаю, нет. Основное понятие синтаксиса это основа. На которую нанизываются обстоятельства. Заметьте они нанизываются не на глагол, не на сказуемое, а на всю основу целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу сложностей:

- Второй день подряд врачи выявляют менее 16 тысяч случаев
  коронавируса.
- два дня подряд он приходил (речь о прошедшем) на работу с опозданием
- два дня подряд он приходит (сегодня второй день) на работу с
  опозданием
- На турнире в Нью-Йорке второй день подряд на трибуны приходит енот.
- В Тегеране протестующие второй день подряд выходят на
  антиправительственные митинги.

Конструкция проста и прозрачна. Всё остальное описывается в настоящем, прошедшем и будущем. Зачем притягивать за уши "второй день подряд", имеющий чёткую семантику - два дня, не более - к иной категории времени?